# How to disable ProgrammaticLogin authentication Netbeans/Glassfish

Tags: authentication, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to run a Netbeans/Glassfish application locally on Windows which is currently running in production on a Unix server. I've succeeded in getting the app up and running, but can't get past the login display due to an authorization exception. I have my name (email) and password set up in the app's database, and have been able to log in to the app running on the Unix server using my credentials. I have connected the Glassfish server to the database via a putty tunnel, and successfully pinged it via the Glassfish admin console.  I've also modified the sun-resources.xml to use the tunneled port for database access.

The way the program is doing authentication is with this code:

```
     boolean authenticateSucceeded=false;
        try {
            ProgrammaticLogin pl=new ProgrammaticLogin();
            authenticateSucceeded=pl.login(user, getEncryptedPassword(password), "mycompany-security-realm", request, response, true);
            String LOGIN_MSG="Login ok for user: "+user;
            logger.info(LOGIN_MSG);

}
        catch (javax.security.auth.login.LoginException e) {
            logger.info("Login exception, user: "+user+", message ="+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Login exception, user: "+user+", message ="+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String forward=null;
        if (authenticateSucceeded)
        {
            forward=URL_HOME_PAGE;
        }
        else{
            forward=LOGIN_ERROR_PAGE;
            String loginComment="Login failed: user ="+user+", fwd ="+forward;
            logger.info(loginComment);
        }
        forward(request,response,forward);
```

Here's a partial stack dump:

```
SEVERE: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Failed file login for myname@mycompnay.com.
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:353)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:199)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:152)
        at com.sun.web.security.WebProgrammaticLoginImpl.login(WebProgrammaticLoginImpl.java:122)
        at com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin$2.run(ProgrammaticLogin.java:259)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Here's the web.xml configured for the login security:

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>MySecureResource</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/stage/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>mycompany-security-realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login/forgotPassword.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

The "mycompany-security-realm" is contained in a generated file called "domain.xml"

```
  <auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm" name="mycompany-security-realm">
      <property name="jaas-context" value="jdbcRealm"/>
      <property name="password-column" value="password"/>
      <property name="group-table" value="grouptable"/>
      <property name="datasource-jndi" value="jdbc/mycompany-sec"/>
      <property name="user-table" value="usertable"/>
      <property name="group-name-column" value="groupid"/>
      <property name="jass-context" value="jdbcRealm"/>
      <property name="db-password" value="xxxx"/>
      <property name="digest-algorithm" value="none"/>
      <property name="db-user" value="mycompanydbuser"/>
      <property name="user-name-column" value="userid"/>
    </auth-realm>
```

When I look at the jdbc specified in domain.xml, it differs from the production version, which is set up on the server to point to a different database. However, when I set it to point to the same database, I get the same exception.

This is a legacy application, and in a worst case scenario I can load it up to the test server and test it up there. However, I would like to run it locally just for form's sake. How can I get this thing working? Or is it better to disable the Authentication, and if so, how? I did try commenting out the auth-realm in web.xml, but had no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
LoginException: Failed file login for myname@mycompnay.com
```

indicates ("Failed **file** login") that your application is not using the JDBC realm you want to use but the default file realm.

The common cause for this is that either the JDBC realm is really not configured in Glassfish or that it is configured in the wrong config. There is a `default-config` section and a `server-config` section in the `domain.xml`. Make sure the JDBC realm is configured in the `server-config`.

To disable the authentication just comment out the `security-constraint` and the `login-config`.